# "Cannot find symbol method loadAd(AdRequest)" when trying to set-up ads by AdMob

Tags: android, admob, ads, symbols, libraries

I'm trying to set-up an ad for my app on Android Studio, but it tells me that it cannot find the symbol method 'loadAd'.

I followed the official guides and even some youtube tutorials but they don't have this problem, that's why I'm asking here.

This is my current list of imports related to ads:

```
import com.google.android.gms.ads.AdRequest;
import com.google.android.gms.ads.MobileAds;
import com.google.android.gms.ads.initialization.InitializationStatus;
import com.google.android.gms.ads.initialization.OnInitializationCompleteListener;
```

While this is the code I'm referring to:

```
MobileAds.initialize(this, new OnInitializationCompleteListener() {
            @Override
            public void onInitializationComplete(InitializationStatus initializationStatus) {
            }
        });
        mAdView = findViewById(R.id.adView);
        AdRequest adRequest = new AdRequest.Builder().build();
        mAdView.loadAd(adRequest);
```

And this is the error I'm getting:

```
error: cannot find symbol method loadAd(AdRequest)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

loadAd() works like this:

```
 interstitialAd = new InterstitialAd(context);
 interstitialAd.setAdUnitId(ID);
 AdRequest adRequest = new AdRequest.Builder().build();
 interstitialAd.loadAd(adRequest);
```

You need to call it on the Ad Object.

More details: https://developers.google.com/admob/android/interstitial

Comment: I have migrated still the loadAd, setAdUnitId methods are not available. Import was interstitial.InterstitialAd

Comment: Lately there have been changes in the SDK.

Answer (score 0):

Add below lib as well along with others

```
import com.google.android.gms.ads.AdView;
```